# widget not returned after condition is "met" (!snapshot.hasData)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a standard `StreamBuilder`. Works fine returning a list from `Firestore`However I want to return a widget when the query is empty. For this I'm using the condition `(!snapshot.hasData)`. But all I get back is an empty screen when the collection is empty. I want to return the `Text Widget`hello :

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: Firestore.instance
                .collection('Events')
                .where("bandId", isEqualTo: identifier)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData)
                return Center(
                    child: Text(
                  'hello',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ));
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return new Text('Loading...');
                default:
                  return new ListView(
                    children:
                        snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                      return Dismissible(
                        key: new Key(document.documentID),
                        onDismissed: (direction) {
                          Firestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
                            DocumentSnapshot snapshot =
                                await transaction.get(document.reference);
                            await transaction.delete(snapshot.reference);
                          });
                          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Event Deleted");
                        },
                        child: CustomCard(
                          event: document['event'],
                          location: document['location'],
                          service: document['service'],
                          date: document['date'].toDate(),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
```

Comment: try wrapping the Text widget into column instead of center

Comment: don't see what difference that'll make..but tried anyway..not working

Comment: can you try this var sEvent = Firestore.instance.collection('Events') .where("bandId", isEqualTo: identifier).snapshots();
Then where you have your stream parameter use 'stream: sEvent,'
I've had a similar problem with FutureBuilder where it doesn't behave properly with commands like 'where', 'then' and 'whenfinished'.

Answer (score 0):

Please try break point on "if (!snapshot.hasData)" to see what you receiving and where your app is going after that(What lines got execute after that), And also there's no {} bracket after if condition.

Comment: if (!snapshot.hasData){
                return Center(
                    child: Text(
                  'hello',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                ));}   
else{                                  
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) { //Your all code